# How to install Pygmentize on MacOS?

Tags: python

I'm trying this to install [pygmentize](https://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/) on GitHub Actions `macos-12` OS:

```
$ pip3 install pygments
$ pygmentize -V
```

However, the first command does install `pygments` Python package, but doesn't install `pygmentize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
    with:
      python-version: '3.10'
  - run: sudo apt-get install -y python3-pygments && sudo pip3 install pygments
    if: matrix.os == 'ubuntu-20.04'
  - run: |
      pip3 install pygments
      easy_install Pygments
      pygmentize -V
    if: matrix.os == 'macos-12'
```

Comment: This seems to be a file. What are the steps you took?

Comment: Who work with GitHub Actions, will understand me :)